# Image not loading with CSS

Tags: css, image, external

Ive referenced several different stack overflow questions, and tried solutions that seem similar to mine and I cant seem to find the answer. Why is the image not loading?

ive tried using these in both a class tag and the body tag. Ive tried backwards and forwards slashes. Ive tried clearing my cache. Ive tried adding additional rules for height width and contain. All to no avail. Ive tried local and pixabay urls as well. 
background-image: image('../img/eye.jpg');
background-image: url("img/eye.jpg");

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles\styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Front Page</h1>      
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

.img-eye {
  background-image: url("https://pixabay.com/photos/dog-bathing-sea-waves-portrait-4565646/");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

body {
  background-image: image('../img/eye.jpg');
  background-color: #000;
}
```

No error messages nothing. Damned thing is dead pan. Code also on js fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/greenthingsjump/htq4os9c/1/

Comment: At least for the pixabay image, you're using an URL to a web page, but you have to link to an image file directly. For your local image, I bet you're just using the wrong relative path. The image has to be relative to the css file, not the html page using that css file. You should see a request resulting in a 404 error status in the Network tab of your dev tools. From that path, you should be able to figure out how the actual path has to look.

Comment: The link should be something like this:
https://pixabay.com/get/52e5d3464c56aa14f6d1867dda6d3e77103fdce7554c704c722d7cdd9f4ecd5a/dog-4565646_1920.jpg

Comment: @blrzzzt has the right answer (beat me to it!); You need to get a direct link to the image, not one a link to a page containing the image, and then make a div or something with the `img-eye` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the image url with a picture extension (jpg, png, svg). You are referencing a page with an embedded image. Try changing the body style to include this url:

`https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/21/10/04/dog-4565646_1280.jpg`

You also aren't using your img-eye class, in case you were unaware.

Answer (score 0):

You're not referencing the "img-eye" class in your html. Also, make sure you're making use of the right path for your image location

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of using the right relative path and remembering to use the class referenced. You guys nailed it. Thanks!